# Converting a automatically allocated std::vector to dynamically allocated std::vector without overhead of copy

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector, stl, c++14

Here I have a automatically allocated `std::vector v`. Now Is there a way to construct another dynamically allocated `std::vector`  from `v` such that there is no overhead of copy constructor.

```
std::vector<int> v(3);
std::vector<int>* v2 = new std::vector<int>(v);
```

1. What happen when destrucotor of `v` is called?
2. Can Someone ellaborate on move constructor of std::vector.
3. Or I should not worry about this as Compiler  will optimise this for me?

I finally want a std::shared_ptr of `v2` which I can pass to some other function.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  If you need to *move* the vector around then just `move` it.

Comment: No, cannot be performed.  You are trying to move a `vector` from one area of memory to another.  You can however use a pointer and pass the pointer around.

Comment: The main question is, why are you creating a dynamically allocated `std::vector` with `new` in the first place?

Comment: @NathanOliver I got return value from a function. Now I want to use it in dynamically allocated memory. As other function take a shared pointer of that variable

Comment: @ThomasMatthews The internal data array is allocated dynamically regardless if the `std::vector` is an automatic object or not.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews actually it can - through swap

Comment: @Snps: the attributes and data members associated in the dynamically allocated array must exist somewhere.  You can't have the attributes exist in one memory and then another without copying *something*.  The `std::vector` is *not* an array and may have attributes.

Comment: @Slava: If you look at a swap algorithm, it involves copying.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/swap says: "Does not invoke any move, copy, or swap operations on individual elements."

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Yes, of course _something_ has to be copied, but those attributes are very cheap to copy. It almost doesn't count.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews if you mean overhead of swapping internal data of `std::vector` then I think you get way to formally to OPs question. It is pretty clear that OP worries about cost of copying elements that vector holds.

Comment: My interpretation of the OP's question is that there should be no overhead in copying *any part of the `std::vector`, including attributes*.  This means No loading from memory into a temporary variable (or memory), and then placing to another.  Fundamentally, there are no moves in a computer; there are copies (although I have seen memory that can have its address changed and still contain the contents).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I just want to avoid overhead of copying elements. I know `std::vector` internally uses `new`, that is why I asked the question. I know answer for generic type is not possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you state that you don't want "overhead of copy constructor", it implies that you no longer need the original vector after creating the "dynamic" one. In that case you can simply do

```
std::vector<int>* v2 = new std::vector<int>(std::move(v));
```

which will use *move* constructor to construct the new vector. The overhead of moving a vector is almost non-existent.

Again, keep in mind that after doing that your original `v` is in "moved from" state - in general case it no longer contains the original data. You can reuse `v` for other purposes. And `v` is still destructible and its destruction will have no effect on `v2`.

Comment: @Ant Thanks, It is possible for any containter

Comment: @Anshuman any container that supports move semantics. All containers from standard C++ library do (assuming you use C++11 or later)

Comment: @Anshuman: In your case, because you want a `shared_ptr` you should use: `std::make_shared<std::vector<int>>(std::move(original))`.